# C++ - How to execute python code using GetDlgItemText?

Tags: c++, python, hwnd

I have a .pyd, that when imported, creates a window in C++, with a Button and Edit box. When you click the button, it grabs the text out of the edit control using something like this:

```
char szString[100000];
GetDlgItemText(hwnd, 2, szString, sizeof(szString));
```

Then, I attempt to run it using PyRun_SimpleString.

```
PyRun_SimpleString(szString);
```

However, When I try to run multiple lines of code, it gives an error like this in python:

```
File "<string>", line 1
print 'Hello, World!'
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How might one fix this?

Comment: Do you have line breaks in the edit control?

Comment: it sounds there is something with the crlf handling...

Comment: Yeah, because when I made it appear in a message box, the text had the correct lining.

Comment: Perhaps the Python code is not expecting Windows cr+lf

Comment: Yep, that is the problem, it's passing in both \r\n, and python just expects \n. Any easy/quick way to fix this?

Comment: Okay, well, I got what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.